# Playing Saved Videos in Documents Dictionary With AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, nsfilemanager

i have saved a 1mb big buck bunny onto my documents folder, and i tried to load and play it with my AVPlayer,for this i used this code

```
 NSString* documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
             NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:string]; // string is file name

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:foofile];
         NSLog(@" exsits %@ :",foofile);


        AVPlayer*player1 = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
        AVPlayerViewController *Controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        Controller.player = player1;
        [player1 play];
        [self presentViewController:Controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but instead of the player i am getting this

[simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36bIt.png)

**EDIT**
File URL looks something like this

> /Users/usrname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4453818A-0617-479B-B98C-3FC544A24D00/data/Containers/Data/Application/D7449628-0A67-4294-9471-98F5596FE596/Documents/tt1823672.mp4

Comment: You're creating your url from `string` instead of `foofile`

Comment: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:foofile];`

Comment: @dan,, sorry, i corrected it but it still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting comment was killing me, so I just post as answer.

As I remembered, if you want to play some local files, the prefix of the url usually is `file://...`.

But if you create url directly, prefix might will be `http://..` .

So you might want to change your code
`[NSURL URLWithString:foofile]`
to
`[NSURL fileURLWithPath:foofile];`

so.. url should had a prefix of `file://..`, and should be target to local files.